# lwc data-table not rendering

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I'm sure that the answer to this question is simple, I just can't seem to see it.

My data table is not rendering any data and I have no idea why. I have reviewed entirely too many examples online and Im sure that I have just become blind to the solution.

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';

const columns = [
    {label: 'string', fieldName: 'string', type: 'text'}
];

const testData = [
    {num: "1", string: "Test1"},
    {num: "2", string: "Test1"},
    {num: "3", string: "Test1"}
];

export default class testLwc extends LightningElement {

}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable key-field='id' data={testData} columns={columns} ></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

Render:

[image: render]

Comment: why havent you declared your properties in your testLwc class? i highly doubt the template is aware of the existence of your data/columns if not declared in the exported classe's properties

Comment: @glls because I am not a javascript developer (I absolutely hate javascript but comments are not the place for my rant). Had Salesforce's compiler thrown some sort of error saying "columns does not exist" it would have saved hours of effort.

Comment: the [Lightning Web Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example) reference library has very good docs and snippets which you can refer to =)

Comment: @glls Thanks, I actually posted another question looking for documentation this weekend because I spent hours googling and had an incredibly hard time finding anything useful. I did eventually find it though and it is what I was using yesterday when I posted this question. If you click the link and view the basic.js example you'll see that it uses consts which is the very thing you told me not to do in your first comment. (although, I do now notice that it also assigns the const to an inner variable).

Comment: yes, the constants are refered to within the the property in the exported class =), my first comment was merely a question as to why you had not refered to the variables within the exported class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variables need to be *in* your class in order to be visible to the template. This simple change should make the table behave normally:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';

export default class testLwc extends LightningElement {
    columns = [
        {label: 'string', fieldName: 'string', type: 'text'}
    ];

    testData = [
        {num: "1", string: "Test1"},
        {num: "2", string: "Test1"},
        {num: "3", string: "Test1"}
    ];    
}
```

---

Obviously, in the most useful case, your variables would most likely use @track, @api, or @wire, but this should get you started.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. I get an error saying that constants cannot be defined in the class. In my real world example I attempted to resolve this error with something like`get columns() {return [...];}` and it was not working. Changing it to `columns = [...];` appears to be enough to get the columns to render. The data in my real world example still does not display even though my `console.log` shows that it is available and in the correct format. Im going to play around with it and if I need more help I'll ask a second question.

Comment: Removed const as it throws an error saying "const can only be used in .ts files".

Comment: I find this a strange behaviour because the docs show that you can instantiate the columns (for example) before the class and then assign the value to another variable inside the class https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example

Comment: @CommonCoreTawan You can create const variables outside the class as in the docs, or directly inside the class as in my example, the problem with OP's code is that they did not assign those values to a variable inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the properties either private @track or public @api. so that any change in the value will rerender the component

```
<template>
    <lightning-datatable key-field='id' data={testData} columns={columns} ></lightning-datatable>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
export default class testLwc extends LightningElement {
    @api columns = [
    {label: 'string', fieldName: 'string', type: 'text'}
    ];

    @api testData = [
    {num: "1", string: "Test1"},
    {num: "2", string: "Test1"},
    {num: "3", string: "Test1"}
    ];

}
```